# Rake: logging any task executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rake

how can I create  database logging for every rake task  without changing source of tasks ? I need to store datetime , task name , parameters . Is there some kind of observer etc ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can override `Rake::Task#invoke` method in `application.rb`:

```
#application.rb
module Rake
  class Task
    alias_method :origin_invoke, :invoke if method_defined?(:invoke)
    def invoke(*args)
      logger = Logger.new('rake_tasks_log.log')
      logger.info "#{Time.now} -- #{name} -- #{args.inspect}"
      origin_invoke(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

output for `rake test`:

```
2011-05-27 16:57:42 +0300 -- test -- []
2011-05-27 16:57:42 +0300 -- test:units -- []
2011-05-27 16:57:51 +0300 -- db:test:load -- []
2011-05-27 16:57:51 +0300 -- db:schema:load -- []
2011-05-27 16:58:19 +0300 -- test:functionals -- []
2011-05-27 16:58:49 +0300 -- test:integration -- []
```

Comment: Please note that `origin_invoke` should be fed with `*args` instead of `args`, otherwise all args will be wrapped in an array and passed as first task parameter (for tasks without parameters – everything works fine).