# how do I get all my rake tasks to write to the same log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, rake

I have two rake tasks that I'd like to run nightly. I'd like them to log to one file. I thought this would do the trick (got it here: [Rake: logging any task executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152159/rake-logging-any-task-executing)):

`application.rb`

```
module Rake
  class Task
    alias_method :origin_invoke, :invoke if method_defined?(:invoke)
    def invoke(*args)
      @logger = Logger.new('rake_tasks_log.log')
      @logger.info "#{Time.now} -- #{name} -- #{args.inspect}"
      origin_invoke(args)
    end
  end
end
```

and then in the `rakefile`:

```
task :hello do
  @logger.warn "Starting Hello task"
  puts "Hello World!"
  puts "checking connection "
  checkConnection
  puts "done checking"
  @logger.debug "End hello rake task"
end
```

But when I run the task I get:

`private method 'warn' called for nil:NilClass`

I've tried a couple of flavors of that call to logging (@, @@, no @) to no avail. Read several threads on here about it. The 
[rubyonrails.org site](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) doesn't mention logging in rake tasks. The tasks that I'm invoking are fairly complex (about 20-40 mins to complete) so I'll really want to know what went wrong if they fail. I'd prefer for DRY reasons to only create the `logger` object once.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're wrapping everything in giant begin/rescue's and catching errors that way, the best way to log errors is to catch all output from stderr and stdout with something like:

```
rake your:job 2>&1 >> /var/log/rake.log
```

You could also set your Rails environment to use the system logger as well.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this (or at least well enough) by making a "log" task and depending on that in other tasks. Not really ideal, since that means having to include that dependency in any new task, but I have only a few tasks so this will do fine. I'm aware that there is a "file" task but it didn't seem to want to work in Windows, so I chose this because it seems to be more cross platform and it's more explicit.

I need a `logger` object because I am passing that object into some method calls in the `[...]` sections. There's enough begin/rescue/end in there that writing to the output stream wouldn't work (I think).

```
@log_file =  "log/tasks.log"
directory "log"

task :check_log => ["log"] do
  log = @log_file
  puts 'checking log existence'
  if not FileTest.exists? ("./#{log}")
    puts 'creating log file'
    File.open(log, 'w')
  end
end

task :check_connection  => [:check_log] do
  begin
    conn = Mongo::Connection.new
    [...]
  end
end


task :nightly_tasks => [:check_connection, :environment ] do
  for i in 1..2
     logger.warn "#########################"
  end
  [...]
  logger.warn "nightly tasks complete"
end

def logger
  @@logger ||= Logger.new( File.join(Rails.root, @log_file) )
end
```